# How can I check the MIME type of an uploaded file using Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, upload, file-upload, cgi

I'm trying to get the MIME type of an `<input type="file" />` element using Perl, but without actually examining the contents of the file itself, In other words, just using the HTTP headers.

I have only been able to get the "multipart/form-type" Content-Type value, but my understanding is that each element will get its own MIME Type?

How can I see the sub-MIME types using Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you are using  [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) to do this. If you are using the OO interface to CGI you can do something like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $filename = $cgi->param('upload_param_name');
my $mimetype = $cgi->uploadInfo($filename)->{'Content-Type'};
```

If you are using the procedural interface, the equivalent would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw/param uploadInfo/;


my $filename = param('upload_param_name');
my $mimetype = uploadInfo($filename)->{'Content-Type'};
```

Comment: This does not show a real mime type. It only shows the same output if you just split the name. I mean this is very unsafe method, since it is easy to cheat it by just changing the extension to a "valid" for the system. But in the real there can be absolutely different content. So, yeah, try Padre::MIME. It has far more options to do a better job for you.